# how to generate x5t header value in golang

Tags: azure, go, base64, fingerprint, hexdump

I have a bash command (from [medium](https://medium.com/@ArsenVlad/certificate-based-auth-with-azure-service-principals-from-linux-command-line-a440c4599cae)) to generate base64 of fingerprint of a certificate.

```
echo $(openssl x509 -in cert.pem -fingerprint -noout) | sed 's/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g' | sed 's/://g' | xxd -r -ps | base64
```

I want to write similar code in golang. I am facing problem in `xxd -r -ps` , how can I implement this xxd in golang?

The output of the command is used as `x5t` header in [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials).

Code which is implemented -

```
data := `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
`
    derBytes, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(data))
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(derBytes.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err ParseCertificate", err)
    }
    fingerprint := sha1.Sum(cert.Raw)

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for i, f := range fingerprint {
        if i > 0 {
            fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "")
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "%02X", f)
    }
    fp := buf.String()
    fmt.Printf("Fingerprint : %s\n", fp) //04B9B0BCB18EF20440DE0ACEC010F6AD9F1B3A94

    // convert fp to byte and then enc in b64
    sEnc := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(fp))
    fmt.Println(sEnc) //MDRCOUIwQkNCMThFRjIwNDQwREUwQUNFQzAxMEY2QUQ5RjFCM0E5NA==
```

The output of openssl cmd is `BLmwvLGO8gRA3grOwBD2rZ8bOpQ=`
and the output the program is `MDRCOUIwQkNCMThFRjIwNDQwREUwQUNFQzAxMEY2QUQ5RjFCM0E5NA==`

Comment: You should show what you have done so far. The only reason you need to use `xxd` is because `openssl` prints byte blobs in hexadecimal, Go gives you access to the raw bytes.

Comment: @Marc updated what i have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building up a bytes buffer with the hexadecimal representation and base64 encoding that string. Instead, you need to base64 encode the raw bytes of the fingerprint.

The hexadecimal representation is just a nicety by openssl, no operations are done on the hexadecimal representation of the data.

Replace the code after computing the fingerprint with the following:

```
fingerprint := sha1.Sum(cert.Raw)

fmt.Printf("%x\n", fingerprint)
// 04b9b0bcb18ef20440de0acec010f6ad9f1b3a94

b64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(fingerprint[:])
fmt.Println(b64)
// BLmwvLGO8gRA3grOwBD2rZ8bOpQ=
```

We can still print the fingerprint in hexadecimal notation, we just use the `%x` verb. The only slightly annoying thing is that we need to use `fingerprint[:]` to turn the array into a slice.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. I was trying to generate fingerprint first without `:` and then convert it into byte and then into base64.

Comment: What if i have only fingerprint stored in the DB. In that case the fingerprint is the only string, how can i convert it in `cert.raw` format?

Comment: You can't. The fingerprint is a checksum, not an encoding, it's not reversible (well, you can try to generate all the possible raw certs and take their checksums, some will match, but that's not exactly practical).

Comment: Basically, my requirement is to convert from  `04b9b0bcb18ef20440de0acec010f6ad9f1b3a94` to `BLmwvLGO8gRA3grOwBD2rZ8bOpQ=`.

Comment: Read the hex representation using [encoding/hex](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/). This will give you raw bytes (same as `fingerprint` above).

Comment: I have tried with `h := sha1.New()`, `h.Write([]byte('"04b9b0bcb18ef20440de0acec010f6ad9f1b3a94")` and `bs := h.Sum(nil)`

Comment: `04...` is the hex representation of the fingerprint, you don't need to take the checksum again, you just need to go from hex back to the raw bytes, then base64 encode. Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/G3UpfSRc94d) instead.